# Go code building error, non standard import "fmt" in standard package, import cycle not allowed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go

I've been working in go for a little while and this weekend I wanted to try to deploy some server code. When I run `go build` on some very simple code to test if Go is working I get this error:

```
can't load package: ($HOME)/go/src/goTest/main.go:4:2: non-standard 
import "fmt" in standard package "goTest"
import cycle not allowed
package goTest
        imports fmt
        imports errors
        imports runtime
        imports runtime/internal/atomic
        imports unsafe
        imports runtime
```

In my ~/.bashrc I'm running this to set environment variables.

```
export GOPATH=/usr/local/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN
```

My go workspace is in `$HOME/go` and my go install is at the default `/usr/local/go`. Any help is appreciated

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("test")
}
```

Edit: `go version` is `go1.6 linux/amd64`

Comment: how odd... maybe it goes away if you follow convention by moving the project to `~/go/src/github.com/nubrozaref/goTest` ?
*edit* nvm your gopath is not ~/go, fix that first. your code needs to live somewhere inside $GOPATH/src

Comment: @Plato Moved it to `/usr/local/go/src/github.com/nubrozaref/goTest` and still getting the import cycle problem, but no mention of non-standard import in the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `$GOPATH`, `$GOROOT`, and `$GOBIN` [correctly](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable). In this case, they should be as follows.

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
export GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
```

Also, locate the source code correctly. Maybe it should be under `$GOPATH/src/github.com/<your id>/<repository name>/`

(If you use newer version of Go (>=1.8), you don't have to set `$GOPATH` and others. [Details here.](https://beta.golang.org/doc/go1.8#gopath))

Comment: @nubrozaref Because `$GOPATH` is different from `$GOROOT`. Read [this reference](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Environment_variables) and [this](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this, but try fixing your paths:

1) `export GOPATH=$HOME/go`.

2) `export GOROOT=/usr/local/go`.

3) `mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/nubrozaref/goTest`

4) `mv $GOPATH/src/goTest/ $GOPATH/src/github.com/nubrozaref/goTest`

5) if you want: `ln -s $GOPATH/src/github.com/nubrozaref/goTest ~/goTest`